# Невозможно зайти на сервер flask

Tags: python, сервер, flask

```
import flask
from flask import *
app = Flask(__name__)
app.route("/index")
def hi():
        return "HELLO WORLD!"
def hello():
    return "2 lazy 2 write sth"
app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Index Page'
def welcome():
 if app.route() == '/index':
            return "Hi welcome to index page!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1000)
```

После этого пытаюсь зайти на 0.0.0.0 192.168.137.1 localhost порт везде 1000
и выдаёт это [image: Ошибка] а в консоле [image: Лог] WELP!

Comment: Забыл добавить знак собачки(декоратор) `@` перед функциями..
`@app.route('/index')`, `@app.route('/')` итд

Answer (score 3):

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Index Page'
```